# c++ overloading operator [] for files

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, filestream

I need to overload the operator `[]` for files, so it will return the character located in the file (easy).
For example `Buff[4]` will return the character at the fourth place:
`ch = Buff[4]`.

I find it difficult to write the code for the opposite situation, in which it changes the character (I know how to work with files).
For example: `Buff[3] = ch` will change Buff at place 3 in the file to `ch`.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: For the second case, you probably need to return a proxy object.... Or just memory map the file...

Answer (score 1):

Return a reference to the character:

```
char& operator[](size_t index)
```

I'm actually a bit stumped for an elegant solution to writing to both at the same time, but you could return a class that keeps track of its index in the buffer and the char value, and writes to both on value change.

```
class BuffSpot
{
    Buff* buff;
    size_t index;
    char val;
    BuffSpot(Buff* b, size_t i, char c) : buff(b), index(i), val(c) {} 
    public:
    char& operator= (const char& right)
    {
        val = right;
        buff->writeToFile(index, val);
        buff->writeToBuff(index, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MatsPetersson I guess I was assuming he was having the buffer written asynchronously, so this changes the char in the buffer and later the buffer is written to the file.